# Group data in nested dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this,

```
data = {'04-01-2012': [{1: 0.93}, {2: 0.9195000000000001}, {3: 0.9090000000000001}, {4: 0.8985000000000002},
                       {5: 0.8880000000000002}, {6: 0.8775000000000003}, {7: 0.8670000000000003},
                       {8: 0.8565000000000004}, {9: 0.8460000000000004}],
        '12-01-2012': [{1: 0.96}],
        '07-01-2012': [{1: 0.96}, {2: 0.95}, {3: 0.94}, {4: 0.9299999999999999}, {5: 0.9199999999999999},
                       {6: 0.9099999999999999}],
        '06-01-2012': [{1: 0.945}, {2: 0.9365}, {3: 0.928}, {4: 0.9195000000000001}, {5: 0.9110000000000001},
                       {6: 0.9025000000000002}, {7: 0.8940000000000002}],
        '10-01-2012': [{1: 0.93}, {2: 0.9244}, {3: 0.9188}],
        '05-01-2012': [{1: 0.935}, {2: 0.926}, {3: 0.917}, {4: 0.908}, {5: 0.899}, {6: 0.89}, {7: 0.881}, {8: 0.872}],
        '11-01-2012': [{1: 0.945}, {2: 0.9325}],
        '02-01-2012': [{1: 0.94}, {2: 0.9299999999999999}, {3: 0.9199999999999999}, {4: 0.9099999999999999},
                       {5: 0.8999999999999999}, {6: 0.8899999999999999}, {7: 0.8799999999999999},
                       {8: 0.8699999999999999}, {9: 0.8599999999999999}, {10: 0.8499999999999999},
                       {11: 0.8399999999999999}],
        '03-01-2012': [{1: 0.955}, {2: 0.9455}, {3: 0.936}, {4: 0.9265000000000001}, {5: 0.9170000000000001},
                       {6: 0.9075000000000002}, {7: 0.8980000000000002}, {8: 0.8885000000000003},
                       {9: 0.8790000000000003}, {10: 0.8695000000000004}],
        '08-01-2012': [{1: 0.94}, {2: 0.9295}, {3: 0.919}, {4: 0.9085000000000001}, {5: 0.8980000000000001}],
        '01-01-2012': [{1: 0.95}, {2: 0.94}, {3: 0.9299999999999999}, {4: 0.9199999999999999}, {5: 0.9099999999999999},
                       {6: 0.8999999999999999}, {7: 0.8899999999999999}, {8: 0.8799999999999999},
                       {9: 0.8699999999999999}, {10: 0.8599999999999999}, {11: 0.8499999999999999},
                       {12: 0.8399999999999999}],
        '09-01-2012': [{1: 0.92}, {2: 0.91}, {3: 0.9}, {4: 0.89}]}
```

I need to iterate over the dictionary values and group all the **1's**, **2's** and so on.

This is my code so far

```
from collections import defaultdict

final = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in data.items():
    new_data = next(iter(v))
    for m, n in new_data.items():
        final[m].append(n)

print(final)

# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [0.935, 0.92, 0.955, 0.96, 0.94, 0.93, 0.95, 0.96, 0.945, 0.94, 0.945, 0.93]})
```

It groups all 1's only, not 2's and so on. What wrong I am doing?

Comment: Your dictionary is pretty strange. For each date you have a list of many tiny dictionaries (one for each key). Preferably you'd start with something like `data = {'04-01-2012': {1: 0.93, 2: 0.9195000000000001, ...`. But maybe that's beyond discussion.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to iterate over the many tiny dictionaries:

```
from collections import defaultdict

final = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in data.items():
    for d in v:                 # <-- this was missing
        for m, n in d.items():
            final[m].append(n)

print(final)
```

(You only called `next(...)`, which yields the first item only.)

Output:

> defaultdict(, {1: [0.96, 0.935, 0.93, 0.945, 0.96, 0.95, 0.93, 0.94, 0.945, 0.955, 0.94, 0.92], 2: [0.926, 0.9244, 0.9365, 0.95, 0.94, 0.9195000000000001, 0.9299999999999999, 0.9325, 0.9455, 0.9295, 0.91], 3: [0.917, 0.9188, 0.928, 0.94, 0.9299999999999999, 0.9090000000000001, 0.9199999999999999, 0.936, 0.919, 0.9], 4: [0.908, 0.9195000000000001, 0.9299999999999999, 0.9199999999999999, 0.8985000000000002, 0.9099999999999999, 0.9265000000000001, 0.9085000000000001, 0.89], 5: [0.899, 0.9110000000000001, 0.9199999999999999, 0.9099999999999999, 0.8880000000000002, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9170000000000001, 0.8980000000000001], 6: [0.89, 0.9025000000000002, 0.9099999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.8775000000000003, 0.8899999999999999, 0.9075000000000002], 7: [0.881, 0.8940000000000002, 0.8899999999999999, 0.8670000000000003, 0.8799999999999999, 0.8980000000000002], 8: [0.872, 0.8799999999999999, 0.8565000000000004, 0.8699999999999999, 0.8885000000000003], 9: [0.8699999999999999, 0.8460000000000004, 0.8599999999999999, 0.8790000000000003], 10: [0.8599999999999999, 0.8499999999999999, 0.8695000000000004], 11: [0.8499999999999999, 0.8399999999999999], 12: [0.8399999999999999]})

Answer (score 0):

```
    new_data = next(iter(v))`
```

This is the line where it goes wrong. This just returns the next value in your iterable, which in this case is the key-value pair bound to key: 1.

you can see this by adding a print statement:

```
from collections import defaultdict

final = defaultdict(list)
print final
for k, v in data.items():

new_data = next(iter(v))
for m, n in new_data.items():
    print new_data

    final[m].append(n)

#{1: 0.96}
#{1: 0.935}
#{1: 0.93}
#{1: 0.945}
#{1: 0.96}
#{1: 0.95}
#{1: 0.93}
#{1: 0.94}
#{1: 0.945}
#{1: 0.955}
#{1: 0.94}
#{1: 0.92}
```

Then the solution is to actually grab all items, instead of just the first, which can be done in a lot of ways, the simplest and ugliest of which is to nest another loop.

```
from collections import defaultdict

final = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in data.items():

    iterable = iter(v)
    for i in range(len(v)):
        new_data = iterable.next()
        for m, n in new_data.items():

            final[m].append(n)

print(final)
```